# Running an .exe in Azure Data

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

So I am working on migrating a project from one of our (to-be deprecated) platforms to Azure Data Factory. That platform can run .exe files.
Here is a brief summary of the system I am migrating:

> 1. Reads multiple TSV files, each file larger than 4 GB
> 2. Run the C# .exe which on the surface does the following:
>    - Extra a base64string from each row from each TSV file
>    - Decode the base64string into a json and populate an object model using this
>    - Create metrics using some details in the object model 
>    - Write these metrics to a TSV file.

Requirement: To migrate the above system to ADF and add some additional components to it.

> Steps 1 and 2 remain the same from above.
> 3. Read the metrics from each row from each of the TSV files.
> 4. Perform some data transformations with read metrics
> 5. Write them to Azure Data Explorer

I know how to do steps 1, 4, 5 but have no clue on how to trigger a .exe in Azure Data Factory and how to read the output of it.

Converting the C# .exe into data flows is not possible having failed pursuing that option.
I have very limited expertise in Azure Services in general. Can someone explain if there is any way to get this done? If possible I would like to use the .exe as is and just supply the inputs to trigger the.exe

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Activity and Azure Batch to run your EXE. Have the EXE write the results to a known location (like Storage or SQL) and then subsequent activities can read those results.